# Cypress iterate table rows get specific element in cells

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to iterate through table rows and get each row which includes a specific value,
but it doesn't work for me.
I'm using `.each()` to iterate the rows and `.within()` on each `$el`,
inside that, I use `cy.get('td').eq(1).contains('hello')` but I the get assertion error:

> Timed out retrying: Expected to find content: 'hello' within the element: `<td>` but never did.

when I console.log `cy.get('td').eq(1)` it yields the desired cell in each row and the test passes, so I don't understand why chaining `.contains()` doesn't work...

```js
it('get element in table', () => {
  cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/');
  cy.get('tbody tr').each(($el) => {
    cy.wrap($el).within(() => {
      cy.get('td').eq(1).contains('hello') // contains() doesn't work
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>$10</td>
      <td>hello</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not `.contains()` that fails, the first row does not contain 'hello' in the second cell - so the test fails and never checks subsequent rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`should('have.text', text)` should work

```
cy.get('td').eq(1).should('have.text', 'hello')
```

If there's whitespace around text, use `contain.text`

```
cy.get('td').eq(1).should('contain.text', 'hello')
```

Comment: From the question it looks like OP is trying to select them. But you're right, judging from the code it does indeed look like your solution is what is actually searched for. Hmm my answer might be in the wrong then

Comment: @Amit Verma, I tried to put your suggestion inside the `.within()` block, instead of `cy.get('td').eq(1).contains('hello')` but it didn't work, still same error

Comment: Based on the html, it looks like you might have to use different index & hello is not there in first row of the table.

Comment: @AmitVerma you're right, when I remove the first row, `contains('hello')` works, how can I skip the rows which doesn't contain "hello" on each iteration?

Comment: See the docs for [conditional testing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#The-DOM-is-unstable)

Answer (score -2):

The simple answer is: don't :)

To be more specific use html attribute selection instead. The convention is to have an attribute named `data-cy`. Furthermore, I discovered it convenient to have a `data-cy-identifier` for when selecting specific rows. Since I'm not sure what you're trying with your code, I'll use a similar example that can hopefully get you going:

```html
<table data-cy="expences">
    <tr>
        <td data-cy="month">January</td>
        <td data-cy="price">$100</td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-cy="discounted">
        <td data-cy="month">Feburary</td>
        <td data-cy="price">$80</td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-cy="discounted">
        <td data-cy="month">March</td>
        <td data-cy="price">$10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can of course do all sorts of combinations of this, but now you can do more specific and useful selections, such as:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="expenses"]').find('[data-cy="discounted"]').find('[data-cy="price"]').should(...)
```

And similar. This is flexible, because it reflects the structure of your data, and not the presentation, so you can change this to a list or whatever later. It avoids selecting of volatile things, so it's also more robust. It also uses a hierarchy rather than overly specific selectors.

The idea of adding things like `data-cy-identifier` allows you to do selections by ID (you can propagate it using javascript, angular, vue or whatever you use) and then checking things like the contents of a row with logically related items.

Hope it can get you going. Also I can  recommend reading: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html

Comment: How can you do that if it's already developed app?

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly understand the question. If I'm to test some existing code, I would just add these selectors to the relevant places and then test them